# Create 1000 Function W/ Leading 0's

Tags: sql, function, scalar, leading-zero

Good Morning DBA's, 
I need a function to pulls an int DocumentID column and returns the lowest thousand int. The limitation is our result must have 8 chars and the leading characters need to be 0's.

- **Example 1**: 1234 (int contained in DocumentID column) Result: 00001000
  (generated by function in result set)
- **Example 2**: 1152534 Result: 01152000

Result Set...

```
DocumentID Function 

1234       00001000 
1152534    01152000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is for SQL Server (based on @Declan_K's answer)

```
SELECT RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), DocumentID  /1000) , 5)+ '000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic structure. The exact commands may vary depending on the RDBMS.

`right('00000000'||cast(DocumentID as varchar(8)),8)`